# How to filter table elements in jsp page based on user selection

Tags: jsp

**index.jsp page**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div align="center">

<form action ="demo.jsp" method="post">
    <table id="formTable">
        <tbody>
        
        <tr>
            <th> <label>START Date: </label> </th>
            <th> <input type = "date" name="Date1" id="date"></th>
         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <label>END Date: </label> </th>
            <th> <input type = "date" name="Date2" id="date"></th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
    
        <td> <label>Author </label> </td>
        <td> <input type ="text" name ="Author" id="author"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    
        <td> <label>Book Name </label> </td>
        <td> <input type ="text" name ="book_Name" id="bookName"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td> <label>Domain </label> </td>
        <td>  <select id="domain" name="Domain" id="domain">
                  <option value ="" selected Disabled>Select Domain</option>
                  <option>Biology</option>
                  <option>chemistry</option>
                  <option>maths</option>
                  
                  </select> </td>
                  </tr>
                  
        
        
        
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type = "submit"  value = "Submit" name = "submit"/>  
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**demo.jsp page**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    
    <body>
    
    
    <div align="center">
    <table id="customers" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td> <label> Id </label> </td>
                <td> <label>book Name </label> </td>
                <td> <label>author </label> </td>
                <td> <label>domain</label></td>
                
                
            </tr>  
        
        
        
            <%
    
        
                      try{
                         
                          String query ="select * from book"
                          Connection conn = SqlConnection.getConnection();
                          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                          while(rs.next()){
                              %>
                              <tr>
                              <td><input type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("Id")%>"> </td>
                              <td><input type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("bookName")%>"> </td>
                              <td><input type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("author")%>"></td>
                              <td><input class ="btn"type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("domain")%>"title="<%=rs.getString("domain")%>"> </td>
                             
                              
                              </tr>
                              <%
                              }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex){
                            System.out.println(ex);
                        }
               %>
        </thead>
    </table>
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

These are my jsp pages - in the index page if a user selects a start date and an end date only reports within that daterange should be selected. If a user fills out any other text fields along with this start and end date it should filter the results according to this field.
For example if I select the start date 01/01/2020 and the end date 28/02/2020 and also the domain 'biology', then the reports with the domain 'biology' should be displayed.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated demo.jsp**

```
<html>


<body>


<div align="center">
<table id="customers" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> <label> Id </label> </td>
            <td> <label>book Name </label> </td>
            <td> <label>author </label> </td>
            <td> <label>domain</label></td>
            
            
        </tr>  
    
    
    
        <%
                 string sdate =request.getParameter("date1");
                 string edate =request.getParameter("date2");
                 string author =request.getParameter("Author");
                 string book =request.getParameter("book_name");
                 string domain =request.getParameter("Domain");

    
                  try{
                     
                      String query ="select * from book where date 
                      between"'+sdate'" and "'+end+'" or author = 
                      "'+author+'" or bookName = "'+book_name+'" or "'+domain'"
                      Connection conn = SqlConnection.getConnection();
                      preparedStatement psmt = conn.createStatement();
                      psmt.setString(1,request.getParameter("date");
                      psmt.setString(2,request.getParameter("date");
                      psmt.setString(3,request.getParameter("author");
                     psmt.setString(4,request.getParameter("bookName");
                     psmt.setString(5,request.getParameter("domain");

                      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                      while(rs.next()){
                          %>
                          <tr>
                          <td><input type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("Id")%>"> </td>
                          <td><input type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("bookName")%>"> </td>
                          <td><input type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("author")%>"></td>
                          <td><input class ="btn"type = text readonly value ="<%=rs.getString("domain")%>"title="<%=rs.getString("domain")%>"> </td>
                         
                          
                          </tr>
                          <%
                          }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex){
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
           %>
    </thead>
</table>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not use query like `select * from book where startdate >= ? and enddate <= ? and domain=?` and then pass value for `?` via preparestatement and execute query to get search results.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but  user may use any one field along with start date and end date or may use all the fields with start date and end date or may not use any field except date fields at that time i think it won't work

Comment: add `or` condition instead of `and` and build your query according to that . i.e :check  if  which fields  are empty don't include them in your query etc .

Comment: I think using an if statement and checking whether the date is `after(date)` or `before(date)` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your responses i tried your ideas i think i'm missing some where can u please give  me demo code so that it would be very help full for me to resolve.

Comment: @bhagya what you have tried please update your question with that ..

Comment: thank you for the concern i updated my code please help to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there are many syntax error in your updated code .. why you are passing value in query as well in setString..?

Comment: i'm new to this field can u please tell me were i'm wrong i can improve it thank you

Comment: Your query should look like `String query ="select * from book where date 
                      between ? and ? or author =  ? or bookName = ? or domain=?"` and then pass value to these parameters using setString..